# side effects of using __attribute__((aligned(X))

Tags: c, gcc, memory-alignment

So i'm seeing an interesting compiler behavior when using the **attribute**((aligned(x)) directive. (i'm using GCC)

consider the following structure

```
typedef struct 
{
  char buffer[4096] __attribute__((aligned(4096));
  int y;
} s1;
```

The structure size is 4100 bytes and must be in 4K aligned address,
when looking at the generated .map file i see the structure is indeed aligned to 4k address but with additional 2 unwanted side effects:

1. There is a padding in between the variable located before my aligned structure - since it is a waste of space how can i make the compiler to try and fill this space with other variables?
2. Not only the structure address is aligned, it also became size aligned, i.e. the variable after it starts also at offset aligned to 4K (i.e. 8K are allocated for a 4100 bytes structure), see below for more details.

**My question**: how do i make the compiler to try and optimize the padding and place variables there (e.g. variables following it) and how do i prevent the compiler to align the structure size to its aligned address?

```
0x00012524      variable1 
0x00012534      [padding]
0x00013000      my_struct (0x4100 bytes but consumes 8192)
0x00015000      variable3
```

Thanks
Vito

Comment: You told the compiler to align and then you want to do not.

Comment: You can't do anything about the trailing padding, that's expected with an aligned object. The best you could hope for is that `variable3` is placed before your `struct` ... maybe an option for optimizing for size (like `-Os`) would help.

Comment: 1) Has nothing to do with the aligned extension - structs must be allocated at even addresses, simple as that.

Comment: @Lundin on 8-bit systems as well?

Comment: @PeterJ Well... yes, since they tend to have 1 byte alignment :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any other way but to declare an additional segment in your linker script and to place the variable there. Place this segment past the .bss and .data segments and you are done :)